# Angular2.0.0 pipe '' could not be found

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Error:

> Error: Template parse errors: The pipe 'datefromiso' could not be
>   found

Pipe:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from "@angular/core";

    @Pipe({
        name: 'datefromiso'
    })
    export class DateFromISO implements PipeTransform {
        transform(value: any, args: string[]): string {
            if (value) {
                var date = value instanceof Date ? value : new Date(value);
                return date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth()+1) + '/' + (date.getYear()+1900);
            }
        }
    }
```

App module:

```
import { DateFromISO } from './pipes/date-from-iso';
...
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [ App ],
  declarations: [
    App,
    ErrorComponent,
    DateFromISO
  ]
```

HTML:

```
<div class="pull-right">{{entity.ts | datefromiso}}</div>
```

`entity.ts` is ISO string. What's wrong? 
Also a question: if there are better way to transform ISO string to locale date in html with angular2?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the HTML in `App` or `ErrorComponent` or some component in another module?

Comment: component in another module, so I need to declare it in that module?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add the module that contains `DateFromISO` to `imports` of every module where you use it.

It's therefore advisable to create a feature module that contains the pipe and perhaps other reusable directives and components and then add this module to `imports` in all modules where they should be available.

The pipe and other reusable components and directives need to be added to `declarations` and `exports` in this feature module.